# MySQL After Insert Trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

Hi this is my very first question here on stackoverflow.com. and kindly excuse for any mistakes in my English as English is not my first language and also I am new to MySQL and php I somehow managed to learn MySQL on my own at home nobody taught me anything so If I am failing at explaining anything in detail please let me know I will try to elaborate the question further. here is my question.

I have four tables:

```
employees (empid, employee_name, designation, start_date)
payroll (payid, month_id, year_id, empid, absents, late_days,)[fk - empid][fk - month_id][fk - year_id]
month (month_id, month)
year (year_id, year)
salary_statement (salary_id, payid, empid, salarymonth, net_salary)
```

I want to create a after insert trigger on payroll to insert month & year(not month_id & year_id I want to insert month from month & year table) in salarymonth column on salary_statement table whenever a new entry has been made

I have tried this but its not working properly

```
BEGIN
    UPDATE salary_statement
    SET SalaryMonth=(SELECT concat(month.month,'/',year.year)
                     FROM month,year
                     WHERE salary_statement.empid=NEW.empid);
END
```

please help me out on this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Pls specify what "not working properly" means.

Comment: Hmm, the where criteria in the update statement should be outside of the parentheses. You also do not need begin - end for a single update statement in a trigger.

Comment: thanks shadow for your effort, I tried joining tables and it worked. thanks again. here is how I made it

INNER JOIN payroll ON payroll.payid=salary_statement.payid
SET SalaryMonth=(SELECT concat(month,'/',year)
FROM month,year
WHERE month.month_id=payroll.month_id
AND year.year_id=payroll.year_id
AND salary_statement.empid=payroll.empid
)